# How to execute a bat file from a classic asp page on the server

Tags: iis, asp-classic, batch-file

I have a simple bat file that runs an access macro when executed, i need to know how to execute this bat file from a asp page, i have given all the permissions to the iusr_machinename for that particular folder containing the script file and the asp file.

Thank you

Note: I don't want to run anything on the client system, i just want to run a bat file on the same system the asp application is running

Comment: You can't run BAT files on a remote machine. And even if you could, it would be a *terrible* idea.

Comment: I don't want to run a bat file on a remote machine, I wnt to run bat file on the server the asp application is installed

Comment: what happens if you just "open" the file with the file system object ?

Comment: @DEE it shows the text in the bat file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you understand the security implications of doing this, the code is as simple as:

```
set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
wshell.run "c:\path\to\file.bat" 
set wshell = nothing
```

I just ran this on a virtual instance without giving any special permissions to IUSR_* and it ran an xcopy without error or interference.

Another issue you will face is when your BAT file throws a prompt or wants to open some kind of dialog.  It's really difficult to handle output, so make sure your BAT file runs without error before looking at further issues with the script.

Whether this code works in your environment is a matter of your security settings.

Answer (score 0):

I finally make this to run changing IIS Application Pool defaults ( identity property ) from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "LocalSystem"