# Unknown error while Executing Batch File in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file

I want to run a batch file on server side in asp.net, I used the following command to execute the batch file. It's working fine when it's running in debug mode, but when I host the URL and call the batch file, it is not working.

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    try
    {


        if (FileUpload1.FileName == "")
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Browse Respective text file";



            return;
        }

        if ((File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/DND_BASE/" + FileUpload1.FileName))) == true)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "File Name already Uploaded";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            string DestFilepath = @"D:\124_SMS_DATA\124_SMS_Base\"+FileUpload1.FileName;
            string SrcFilepath = Server.MapPath("~/DND_BASE/") + FileUpload1.FileName;


            FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/DND_BASE/"), FileUpload1.FileName));
            if (File.Exists(DestFilepath))
            {
                File.Delete(DestFilepath);

            }
            File.Move(SrcFilepath, DestFilepath);
            Label5.Visible = true;
            Label5.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully You can download file after 5 Mins";
            string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\test.bat";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);





        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        err = new ErrorHandler();
        err.WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have typed your command and I can confirm. It doesn't work here either

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't run a batch file in ASP, because it runs under the permissions of the ASP user when its on a server(which for obiouse reasons is very limited) .

Your best bet is to create a scheduled job on the asp server that runs every so often and checks a folder or file that your ASP page creates or changes and then fire off events from that.

Comment: however, really this question could be seen as a duplicate..see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644689/how-to-execute-a-bat-file-from-a-classic-asp-page-on-the-server

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your goal, but please keep this in mind-  The *batch* will run on the *Local Machine*.  If you intend to run remotely, I'd look into *Powershell*.  Also you will encounter several *permission issues*.  Several *batch* request will require **elevated** permissions. Otherwise the proper way to **execute a batch file from C# is like so:**

```
using (Process.Start(@"C:\Batch\File\Location\AndName.bat"))
{
    // Additional Requirements / Manipulation if Required.
}
```

This way it will actually *dispose* of the resources once your *batch* completes.  The other alternative would be to attempt to *execute the batch with elevated permissions*.  As I stated though before, you really should utilize *Powershell* as it will have access to the *Windows Management Interface (WMI)*.

Also if you are sure about the whole *batch* then you'll really want to ensure you test *Permissions* very thoroughly. Otherwise you may encounter large errors-  So familiarizing yourself with the *User Access Control* and ensure your *Client* can invoke a *service* to run that *batch* to your given machine.  Be aware that you are exposing potential security issues if your data becomes malformed- As you could allow someone to alter the request to run an elevated script that is malicious.

Hopefully that at least helps.

Comment: HI Thanks for all your comments. Here is my full code what I want is I have a webpage where the end user can upload a file once the file upload on a server, I need to run a ms-access macro file on server finally macro will generate a file , then that file will be downloadable by the user.. to call the macro I simply used batch file on the server side

Comment: Hi Thanks i have scheduled the batch file.. its working fine now.. thank you all!!!